# Exim проблема спама, который я не отправлял

Tags: ispmanager, exim

**Помогите найти проблему в exim. В очереди вижу письма которые я не отправлял и даже мои почтовые ящики там не фигурируют. Вот пример лога:**

```
> 2019-10-26 16:31:55 auth_login authenticator failed for (User) [185.234.216.144]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=sales1@MY_DOMAIN)
2019-10-26 16:32:51 no host name found for IP address 129.205.112.141
2019-10-26 16:32:53 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X From info@lee.org to norrisbox@gmail.com, senatordavidmark70@outlook.com, senatordavidmark70@onet.pl, katenash_55@aol.com, info.interpol_usa@yahoo.com X-Spam_score: . 50
2019-10-26 16:32:53 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X <= info@lee.org H=([192.168.43.132]) [129.205.112.141] P=esmtp S=4341 from <info@lee.org> for norrisbox@gmail.com senatordavidmark70@outlook.com senatordavidmark70@onet.pl katenash_55@aol.com info.interpol_usa@yahoo.com
2019-10-26 16:32:53 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:400c:c09::1b] Network is unreachable
2019-10-26 16:32:54 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [108.177.15.26]: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data: 421-4.7.0 [MY_IP      15] Our system has detected that this message is\n421-4.7.0 suspicious due to the very low reputation of the sending IP address.\n421-4.7.0 To protect our users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has\n421-4.7.0 been temporarily rate limited. Please visit\n421 4.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information. j10si4829165wrx.215 - gsmtp
2019-10-26 16:32:54 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X H=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b] Network is unreachable
2019-10-26 16:32:54 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X H=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [209.85.233.27]: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data: 421-4.7.0 [MY_IP      15] Our system has detected that this message is\n421-4.7.0 suspicious due to the very low reputation of the sending IP address.\n421-4.7.0 To protect our users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has\n421-4.7.0 been temporarily rate limited. Please visit\n421 4.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information. l19si5315574lfh.54 - gsmtp
2019-10-26 16:32:54 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X H=alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2404:6800:4003:c04::1a] Network is unreachable
2019-10-26 16:32:54 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X H=alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2404:6800:4008:c00::1b] Network is unreachable
2019-10-26 16:32:54 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X H=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:400e:c00::1a] Network is unreachable
2019-10-26 16:32:54 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X == norrisbox@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (101): Network is unreachable H=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [209.85.233.27]
2019-10-26 16:32:55 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X => senatordavidmark70@outlook.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com [104.47.37.33] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=mail.protection.outlook.com" K C="250 2.6.0 <f6885c68-0f0a-4333-b7ec-f6292d004644@CY1NAM02FT051.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com> [InternalId=60644938271059, Hostname=CY1NAM02HT077.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com] 11341 bytes in 0.275, 40.254 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery -> 250 2.1.5"
2019-10-26 16:32:55 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X ** senatordavidmark70@onet.pl R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mx.poczta.onet.pl [213.180.147.146] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/C=PL/ST=MAZOWIECKIE/L=WARSZAWA/O=Ringier Axel Springer Polska Sp z o.o./OU=IT Operations/CN=*.poczta.onet.pl": SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<senatordavidmark70@onet.pl>: 554 5.7.1 <senatordavidmark70@onet.pl>: Recipient address rejected: Spf check: fail
2019-10-26 16:32:56 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X ** katenash_55@aol.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mx-aol.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net [67.195.228.84] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes DN="/C=US/ST=California/L=Sunnyvale/O=Oath Inc/CN=*.am0.yahoodns.net": SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 554 5.7.9 Message not accepted for policy reasons.  See https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN7253.html
2019-10-26 16:32:57 1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X ** info.interpol_usa@yahoo.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mta5.am0.yahoodns.net [67.195.228.110] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes DN="/C=US/ST=California/L=Sunnyvale/O=Oath Inc/CN=*.am0.yahoodns.net": SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 554 5.7.9 Message not accepted for policy reasons.  See https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN7253.html
2019-10-26 16:32:57 1iOMBd-0004qz-5y <= <> R=1iOMBZ-0004qm-0X U=exim P=local S=6935 from <> for info@lee.org
2019-10-26 16:32:59 1iOMBd-0004qz-5y ** info@lee.org R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=vade-in1.mail.dreamhost.com [66.33.205.212] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Provided by New Dream Network, LLC/OU=DreamHost Basic Wildcard SSL/CN=*.mail.dreamhost.com": SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<info@lee.org>: 550 5.7.1 <info@lee.org>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown.
2019-10-26 16:32:59 1iOMBd-0004qz-5y Frozen (delivery error message)
2019-10-26 16:33:51 auth_login authenticator failed for (User) [93.174.93.5]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=postmaster@MY_DOMAIN)
2019-10-26 16:36:15 TLS error on connection from c-ee02e655.02010028-0-6f70706e6173746164736e6174.bbcust.telenor.se [85.230.2.238] (SSL_accept): error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
```

**exim --version
Exim version 4.92.3 #3 built 30-Sep-2019 11:50:17**

```
DKIM_ENABLE = yes
SA_ENABLE = yes
SA_SPAMD_USER = root
SA_SCORE_REJECT = 50
SA_ABUSE_ADDR = The System Administrator
log_selector =  \
        +all_parents \
        +lost_incoming_connection \
        +received_sender \
        +received_recipients \
        +tls_cipher +tls_peerdn +tls_sni \
        +smtp_confirmation \
        +smtp_syntax_error \
        +smtp_protocol_error

# TLS/SSL
tls_advertise_hosts = *
tls_certificate = ${if exists{/etc/exim/ssl/${tls_sni}.crt}{/etc/exim/ssl/${tls_sni}.crt}{/etc/exim/ssl/exim.crt}}
tls_privatekey = ${if exists{/etc/exim/ssl/${tls_sni}.key}{/etc/exim/ssl/${tls_sni}.key}{/etc/exim/ssl/exim.key}}
daemon_smtp_ports = 25 : 465 : 587
tls_on_connect_ports = 465

.ifdef SA_ENABLE
spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 783
.endif

trusted_groups = mgrsecure
trusted_users = apache

keep_environment =

domainlist local_domains = lsearch;/etc/exim/domains
domainlist dummy_domains =
hostlist relay_from_hosts = 127.0.0.1 : MY_IP

domainlist relay_to_domains = lsearch;/etc/exim/domains
exim_user = exim
exim_group = exim

.ifdef VIRUS_SCAN
av_scanner = clamd:__CLAMAV_SOCKET__
.endif

never_users = root
host_lookup = *
rfc1413_hosts = *
rfc1413_query_timeout = 0s
ignore_bounce_errors_after = 2d
timeout_frozen_after = 7d
acl_smtp_rcpt = acl_check_rcpt
acl_smtp_data = acl_check_data
acl_not_smtp = acl_check_not_smtp
.ifdef DKIM_ENABLE
acl_smtp_dkim = acl_check_dkim
.endif

begin acl

        acl_check_not_smtp:
                # check ratelimits by local user
                warn    condition       = ${if match_local_part{$sender_ident}{lsearch;/etc/exim/ratelimits} {yes}{no}}
                                set     acl_c9  = $sender_ident
                warn    condition       = ${if match_local_part{$sender_address}{lsearch;/etc/exim/ratelimits} {yes}{no}}
                                set acl_c9      = $sender_address
                deny    set     acl_c8 = ${lookup{$acl_c9}lsearch*{/etc/exim/ratelimits}}
                                condition       = ${if and{{!eq{$acl_c9}{}}{>{$acl_c8}{0}}}{yes}{no}}
                                ratelimit       = $acl_c8 / 1h / strict / $acl_c9
                                message         = Sender rate overlimit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period / $acl_c9
.ifdef DEFAULT_RATELIMIT
                # check ratelimits by default
                warn    set acl_c7      = $sender_ident
                warn    condition       = ${if eq{$acl_c7}{} {yes}{no}}
                                set acl_c7      = $sender_address
                deny    condition       = ${if and{{!eq{$acl_c7}{}}{eq{$acl_c8}{}}}{yes}{no}}
                                ratelimit       = DEFAULT_RATELIMIT / 1h / strict / $acl_c7
                                message         = Sender rate overlimit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period / $acl_c7
.endif

                accept

        acl_check_rcpt:

.ifdef VIRUS_SCAN
                warn
                    set acl_m3 = no
                warn
                    condition = ${lookup{$domain}lsearch{__CLAMAV_WHITELIST__} {yes}{no}}
                    set acl_m3 = ok
.endif

                accept  hosts = +relay_from_hosts
                                !authenticated = *
                set acl_m6 = whitelisted

                accept  domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains
                                condition = ${lookup{$sender_address}wildlsearch{/etc/exim/whitelist}{yes}{no}}
                                set acl_m6 = whitelisted
                                logwrite = Accepted from $sender_address to $local_part@$domain by whitelist.

                accept  domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains
                                hosts = net-lsearch;/etc/exim/whitelist
                                set acl_m6 = whitelisted
                                logwrite = Accepted from $sender_address to $local_part@$domain by whitelist.

                deny    condition = ${lookup{$sender_address}wildlsearch{/etc/exim/blacklist}{yes}{no}}
                                set acl_m6 = blacklisted
                                logwrite = Rejected from $sender_address to $local_part@$domain by blacklist.

                deny    hosts = net-lsearch;/etc/exim/blacklist
                                set acl_m6 = blacklisted
                                logwrite = Rejected from $sender_address to $local_part@$domain by blacklist.

                deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
                                domains       = +local_domains
                                local_parts   = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|]

                deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
                                domains       = !+local_domains
                                local_parts   = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!] : ^.*/\\.\\./

                accept  local_parts   = postmaster
                                verify        = recipient
                                domains       = +local_domains

                require verify        = sender

                # check ratelimits by emails
                warn    authenticated = *
                                set acl_c0      = group${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}
                                set acl_c1      = ${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch*{/etc/exim/ratelimits}}
                                ratelimit       = ${lookup{$acl_c0}lsearch*{/etc/exim/ratelimits}} / 1h / strict / $acl_c0
                                ratelimit       = $acl_c1 / 1h / strict / $authenticated_id
                                log_message     = Sender rate overlimit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period / $authenticated_id
                                condition       = ${if match_local_part{$authenticated_id}{lsearch;/etc/exim/ratelimits} {yes}{no}}
                deny    authenticated = *
                                set acl_c1      = ${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch*{/etc/exim/ratelimits}}
                                ratelimit       = $acl_c1 / 1h / leaky / $authenticated_id
                                message         = Sender rate overlimit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period / $authenticated_id
                                condition       = ${if match_local_part{$authenticated_id}{lsearch;/etc/exim/ratelimits} {yes}{no}}
                # check ratelimits by group
                warn    authenticated = *
                                set acl_c0      = group${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}
                                ratelimit       = ${lookup{$acl_c0}lsearch*{/etc/exim/ratelimits}} / 1h / strict / $acl_c0
                                log_message     = Sender rate overlimit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period / $acl_c0
                                condition       = ${if match_local_part{$acl_c0}{lsearch;/etc/exim/ratelimits} {yes}{no}}
                deny    authenticated = *
                                set acl_c0      = group${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}
                                ratelimit       = ${lookup{$acl_c0}lsearch*{/etc/exim/ratelimits}} / 1h / leaky / $acl_c0
                                message         = Sender rate overlimit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period / $acl_c0
                                condition       = ${if match_local_part{$acl_c0}{lsearch;/etc/exim/ratelimits} {yes}{no}}
.ifdef DEFAULT_RATELIMIT
                # check ratelimits by default
                deny    authenticated = *
                                ratelimit       = DEFAULT_RATELIMIT / 1h / strict / $authenticated_id
                                message         = Sender rate overlimit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period / $authenticated_id
                                condition       = ${if or{{eq{$acl_c1}{}}{eq{$acl_c0}{}}}{yes}{no}}
.endif

                accept  hosts         = +relay_from_hosts
                                !authenticated = *
                                control       = submission/sender_retain

                accept  authenticated = *
                                condition     = ${if eq{${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}}{no} {yes}{no}}
                                condition     = ${if eq{${extract{3}{:}{${lookup{${domain:$authenticated_id}}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains}}}}}{no} {yes}{no}}
                                control       = submission/domain=
#deny
                deny    message       = rejected because $sender_host_address is in a black list at $dnslist_domain\\n$dnslist_text
                                dnslists      = ${readfile {/etc/exim/dnsbllist}{:}}

                require message       = relay not permitted
                                domains       = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

                require verify        = recipient

.ifdef POSTGREY_SOCKET
                defer log_message = greylisted host $sender_host_address
                        set acl_m0  = request=smtpd_access_policy\nprotocol_state=RCPT\nprotocol_name=${uc:$received_protocol}\nhelo_name=$sender_helo_name\nclient_address=$sender_host_address\nclient_name=$sender_host_name\nsender=$sender_address\nrecipient=$local_part@$domain\ninstance=$sender_host_address/$sender_address/$local_part@$domain\n\n
                        set acl_m0  = ${sg{${readsocket{POSTGREY_SOCKET}{$acl_m0}{5s}{}{action=DUNNO}}}{action=}{}}
                        message     = ${sg{$acl_m0}{^\\w+\\s*}{}}
                        condition   = ${if eq{${uc:${substr{0}{5}{$acl_m0}}}}{DEFER}{true}{false}}
.endif

                accept

        acl_check_data:

            accept
                condition = ${if >{$load_average}{3000} {yes}{no}}
                logwrite = Accept message without spamd and antivirus check because LA > 3.

.ifdef VIRUS_SCAN
        accept
            condition = ${if >{$message_body_size}{2M} {yes}{no}}
            logwrite = Accept message without antivirus check because body size $message_body_size not critical

        warn
            condition = ${if eq{$acl_m3}{no} {yes}{no}}
            add_header = X-Scanned-By: ${extract{1}{/}{${readsocket{__CLAMAV_SOCKET__}{VERSION}{1s}{} {unscanned}}}}; $tod_full\n

        deny
            message = This message contains virus ($malware_name)
            hosts   = *
            malware = *
            log_message = Rejected: this message contains virus ($malware_name)
            condition = ${if eq{$acl_m3}{no}{yes}{no}}
.endif
.ifdef SA_ENABLE
        warn
            !authenticated = *
            hosts = !127.0.0.1/24
            condition = ${if < {$message_size}{1K}}
            spam       = SA_SPAMD_USER:true
            add_header = X-Spam_score: $spam_score\n\
                   X-Spam_score_int: $spam_score_int\n\
                   X-Spam_bar: $spam_bar\n\
                   X-Spam_report: $spam_report
           logwrite = From $sender_address to $recipients X-Spam_score: $acl_m4. SA_SCORE_REJECT

        warn
            !authenticated = *
            hosts = !+relay_from_hosts
            spam       = SA_SPAMD_USER:true/defer_ok
            add_header = X-Spam_score: $spam_score\n\
                    X-Spam_score_int: $spam_score_int\n\
                    X-Spam_bar: $spam_bar\n\
                    X-Spam_report: $spam_report
            set acl_m4 = $spam_score_int
            condition = ${if and{{>{$message_size}{1K}}{>{$acl_m4}{SA_SCORE_REJECT}}} {yes}{no}}
            logwrite = From $sender_address to $recipients X-Spam_score: $acl_m4. SA_SCORE_REJECT
            #condition = ${{if >{$acl_m4}{20}} {yes}{no}}
            add_header = Subject: ***SPAM (score: $spam_score) $rh_Subject:
            #logwrite = SPAMSCORE_DIMA $spam_score_int

        #deny
        #       condition = ${if and{{>{$message_size}{10K}}{!eq{$acl_m4}{}}{>{$acl_m4}{SA_SCORE_REJECT}}} {yes}{no}}
        #       add_header = Subject: ***SPAM (score: $spam_score) $rh_Subject:
        #    message = Content analisis tool detect spam (from $sender_address to $recipients). Contact SA_ABUSE_ADDR.
        #    ###Dima
        #    #logwrite = SA_ABUSE_ADDR - SA_SCORE_REJECT --> $sender_address --$ack_m4
.endif

                accept

.ifdef DKIM_ENABLE
        acl_check_dkim:

        warn
            dkim_status = fail
            logwrite = DKIM test failed: $dkim_verify_reason
            add_header = X-DKIM-FAIL: DKIM test failed: (address=$sender_address domain=$dkim_cur_signer), signature is bad.

        warn
            dkim_status = invalid
            add_header = :at_start:Authentication-Results: $dkim_cur_signer ($dkim_verify_status); $dkim_verify_reason
            logwrite = DKIM test passed (address=$sender_address domain=$dkim_cur_signer), but signature is invalid.

        accept
            dkim_status = pass
            add_header = :at_start:Authentication-Results: dkim=$dkim_verify_status, header.i=@$dkim_cur_signer
            logwrite = DKIM test passed (address=$sender_address domain=$dkim_cur_signer), good signature.

        accept
.endif

begin routers
        dnslookup:
                driver = dnslookup
                domains = !+dummy_domains
                transport = remote_smtp
                ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8
                self = pass
                no_more

        disabled_domains:
                driver = redirect
                condition = ${extract{3}{:}{${lookup{$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains}}}}
                allow_fail = yes
                data = :fail: Domain disabled
                no_more

        disabled_users:
                driver = redirect
                condition = ${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}
                allow_fail = yes
                data = :fail: User disabled
                no_more

        local_domains:
                driver = redirect
                condition = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}{no}{yes}}
                data = ${quote_local_part:$local_part}@${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains}}}}
                cannot_route_message = Unknown user
                redirect_router = dnslookup
                no_more

        aliases:
                driver = redirect
                data = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/aliases}}}}
                condition = ${if exists{/etc/exim/aliases} {yes} {no} }
                redirect_router = dnslookup
                pipe_transport = address_pipe

        procmail:
                no_verify
                driver = accept
                #local_part_suffix = +*
                #local_part_suffix_optional
                transport = dovecot_deliver_pipe
                transport_home_directory = ${extract{4}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}
                condition = ${lookup {$local_part@$domain} lsearch {/etc/exim/passwd} {yes} {no} }
                #no_more

        local_users:
                driver = accept
                local_part_suffix = +*
                local_part_suffix_optional
                transport = local_delivery
                condition = ${lookup {$local_part@$domain} lsearch {/etc/exim/passwd} {yes} {no} }
                #no_more

        catchall_for_domains:
                driver = redirect
                headers_add = X-redirected: yes
                data = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains}}}}
                file_transport = local_delivery
                redirect_router = dnslookup

        unknown_users:
                driver = redirect
                allow_fail = yes
                data = :fail: Unknown user
                no_more

begin transports

        remote_smtp:
                driver = smtp

.ifdef DKIM_ENABLE
                headers_add = "List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:$sender_address?subject=Unsubscribe>"
                #, <https://$sender_address_domain/unsubscribe.php?unsubscribe=1&unsubscribed_email=$local_part@$domain>"
                dkim_domain = $sender_address_domain
                dkim_selector = ${if exists{/etc/exim/ssl/$sender_address_domain.txt}{${extract{1}{.}{${readfile{/etc/exim/ssl/$sender_address_domain.txt}}}}}{dkim}}
                dkim_private_key = ${if exists{/etc/exim/ssl/$sender_address_domain.private}{/etc/exim/ssl/$sender_address_domain.private}{0}}
.endif

                interface = <;${lookup{$sender_address_domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domainips}}

        local_delivery:
                driver = appendfile
                maildir_format = true
                maildir_use_size_file = true
                create_directory = true
                directory_mode = 700
                directory = ${extract{4}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}/.maildir
                delivery_date_add
                envelope_to_add
                return_path_add
                mode = 0660
                quota = ${extract{3}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}M
                quota_warn_threshold = 75%
                use_lockfile = no
                no_mode_fail_narrower
                user = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}
                group = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}


        address_pipe:
                driver = pipe
                ignore_status
                return_output
                use_shell

        dovecot_deliver_pipe:
                driver = pipe
                environment = "HOME=$home"
                command = "/usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $local_part@$domain  -f $sender_address"
                return_path_add
                delivery_date_add
                envelope_to_add
                check_string = "From "
                escape_string = ">From "
                user = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}
                group = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/passwd}}}}

begin retry
*               *               F,2h,15m; G,16h,1h,1.5; F,4d,6h

begin rewrite

begin authenticators


           auth_plain:
                   driver = dovecot
                   public_name = PLAIN
                   server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
                   server_set_id = $auth1

           auth_login:
                   driver = dovecot
                   public_name = LOGIN
                   server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
                   server_set_id = $auth1

           auth_cram_md5:
                   driver = dovecot
                   public_name = CRAM-MD5
                   server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
                   server_set_id = $auth1
```

**log - debug**

```
https://fex.net/s/zstxsce
```

Comment: Вот бы вы его отформатировали как следует... А так, судя по P=esmtp (без "a") в логе, вы умудрились сконфигурировать open relay, это у exim'а не дефолт.

Comment: Это панель ISPManager, в конфиг вносил небольшие правки. Буду благодарен если укажите где косяк). Добавил конфиг

Comment: Если правильно понял - моя ошибка тут: #deny
        #       condition = ${if and{{>{$message_size}{10K}}{!eq{$acl_m4}{}}{>{$acl_m4}{SA_SCORE_REJECT}}} {yes}{no}}
        #       add_header = Subject: ***SPAM (score: $spam_score) $rh_Subject:

Comment: А  129.205.112.141 — это ваш адрес или нет? И не совпадает ли он с MY_IP? И что у вас в /etc/exim/domains и /etc/exim/whitelist?

Comment: Нет, IP не мой. Позже отпишусь что в файлах

Comment: /etc/exim/domains  - стоит 3 моих домена почтовых; /etc/exim/whitelist - список почтовых ящиков и доменов (пример домена в таком виде *@gmail.com)

Comment: Только что проверил очередь - опять висит замороженное письмо, которое я не отправлял. Мое предположение об ошибке описанной выше - ошибочно)

Comment: Есть идеи? у меня уже 100500 замороженных писем

Comment: У меня идеи кончились. Переходите к отладке с `-bt -d+all -oMa` и т. п. вуду.

Comment: Сменил пароли на всех почтовых ящиках, это было сложно... но пока тишина. Есть подозрение что слили пароль

Comment: Было бы "P=esmtpa" или "P=esmtpsa" в строке получения.

Comment: Отладчиком очень сложно словить, так как проблема не постоянная, а может проявляться раз в 3 дня.  Есть подозрение что отправители подставляют мой адрес и письмо возвращается на мой сервер как mail delivery:

Comment: 156P Received: from exim by email.MYDOMAIN with local (Exim 4.92.3)
        for test@jzbgno.hospedagemweb.net;
094  X-Failed-Recipients: barrister_emmanuel62@yahoo.com,
  union_bnk_customer_service@outlook.com
029  Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
062F From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@email.MYDOMAIN>
034T To: test@jzbgno.hospedagemweb.net
100  Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status; boundary=1573049516-eximdsn-1751569889
059  Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender

Comment: Выгрузил log debug - выручайте